# SWIFT "3 levels array"

Tags: swift, string, data-modeling

I have a little problem with using arrays and declaring it in swift 5 on OSX:

- I know an `[[String]]` is an array of arrays like `[["team1", "2 goals"], ["team2", "0 goals"]]`. Well it's easy for my, but let me explain my case:
- I have an array of "Systems", which is like -> `["nes", "Xbox" , "ps2"]`
- every "System" have "Games" and every "game" in "Games" have an array of properties like "name", "thumbnail", "video", etc...

I need to create an array like ->

```
["xbox" , [["game1",array of properties],["game2", array of properties]]]
```

I tried to define an `[[[String]]]`

```
var allMyGames = [[[String]]]()
```

but I don´t know how to myGames.append this...

I have an array named `myGames = [[String]]()` which contains data like ["game1", "property1", "property2" ,"property3"] ["game2", "property1", "property2" ,"property3"]

and another array with the systems `mySystems = [String]()` my contains data like `["nes", "xbox", "ps2"]`

Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: You're using arrays to model data that isn't array-like, and that's always going to make things difficult. I think you should look into using structs to model your data. It looks like You'll want a `Game` and `GameSystem` struct, then you can make something like a `supportedGames: [Game]` field on your `GameSystem` struct. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: You would be much better off by modelling your data as Structs rather than using arrays like this.

Comment: Yeah, arrays are only a good fit when you have a variable number of the same thing, like game consoles, or games. it makes sense to have an array of consoles. However, a Console object should probably be a struct, as should a Game. inside the Game struct would be fields for the different properties of a game.

Comment: There are cases where a 3-dimensional array might be a good choice, but this does not seem like one of those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better modelling your problem using structs. Here is a start for you to show how you might start modelling your problem.

OK, let's start by creating a game with a name, thumbnail image and video.

```
struct Game {
  let name: String
  let thumbnailURL: URL
  let videoURL: URL
}
```

Now we can create a system...

```
struct System {
  let name: String
  let games: [Game]
}
```

And now you can create your array of systems...

```
let systems = [
  System(
    name: "Xbox",
    games: [
      Game(name: "Halo", thumbnailURL: ... videoURL: ...),
    ]
  ),
  System(
    name: "NES",
    games: [
      Game(name: "Super Mario Bros", thumbnailURL: ... videoURL: ...),
    ]
  )
]
```

As you can see you end up with a much easier way to model the different systems and games etc...

Comment: Im retrieving data fron multiple xml files, so i need to populate everything programmatically. Can you give me an example of populating the system struct programmatically and itinerate through the systems, im better in the arrays way and not much in the struct way

Comment: That very much depends on what your data looks like. Does it have to be xml? It would make more sense for it to be json data. But, have a search for the Codable protocol. It will help you here. Otherwise you should ask a new question to get further help with this.

Comment: I mean how to populate the system array you proposed as in a for loop. I can parse xml without problems

Comment: This is out of scope of the question you asked and so really should be a new question. I’d recommend asking a question and showing how you are currently parsing the xml. That way we can work with what you currently have to improve your code. This question doesn’t show anything about parsing the data from xml.